# Face map not well-defined on oriented simplices

Tags: algebraic-topology, simplex

Currently I am facing this problem with the face map $d_i$ (delete the $i$th vertex). It is not well-defined on oriented simplices.

For instance,
$d_0[v_0,v_1,v_2]=[v_1,v_2]$, but $d_0[v_2,v_0,v_1]=[v_0,v_1]$.

Is there a known way to ensure that this does not happen?

I thought of the following: we order the vertices and impose the rule of always writing simplices in ascending order of vertices, with a negative sign if necessary.

For instance $d_0(-[v_0,v_1,v_2])=-[v_1,v_2]$.

In essence, I wish to find a working definition such that the $i$-th face of any simplex $\sigma$, $d_i\sigma$, is well-defined.

Does the method outlined above work? Is there a name for such construction? Thanks.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with this, exactly?  I would guess that you should just take an altogether different approach to your underlying problem.

Comment: @EricWofsey I not trying to do anything deep. Just notationally, I would like to fix a notation for $d_i\sigma$ that is well-defined.

Comment: Well, why do you want it to be well-defined?  And why do you want to work with oriented simplices (as opposed to ordered simplices) in the first place?  Generally things tend to work much better if you use ordered simplices.

Comment: Your attempt is doomed! The overall boundary $d_0-d_1+d_2-\cdots$ will be well-defined, but the individual terms won't.

Comment: I mean, you can make the definition you propose, but if you're doing that then why consider oriented simplices at all instead of just using only ordered simplices in your "ascending order"?

Comment: @EricWofsey I am interested to do homology too and define the boundary map $\partial(\sigma)=\sum_i (-1)^i d_i(\sigma)$, satisfying $\partial^2=0$. Hence, I need oriented simplices? I am not familiar with ordered simplices, will it suffice for doing homology?

Comment: If you're just interested in defining the boundary map for homology there is no issue at all; it is well-defined even if the individual $d_i$ are not.  I can expand on this in an answer if you want.

Comment: @EricWofsey I roughly understand that since the $i$ runs from 0 to $n$, overall it is well-defined since we take the sum in the boundary operator. I am actually working on a school project where I need a particular way to say, $d_i\sigma$ is the i-th face of the simplex $\sigma$, without being ambiguous.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Can you briefly explain why my attempt (the part on fixing ascending ordering in simplices) is doomed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usual approach here is to define a "simplex" to come with a specific ordering of the vertices.  So, you would simply say that $[v_0,v_1,v_2]$ and $[v_2,v_0,v_1]$ are *different* simplices, and there is no problem with $d_0$ taking different values on them.

If you are talking about the simplices of a simplicial complex, then it would furthermore be usual to fix a single total order of the vertex set, and allow only simplices whose vertices are in that order.  So, only $[v_0,v_1,v_2]$ would be considered a simplex in your complex at all, and $[v_2,v_0,v_1]$ would be a meaningless symbol.  This is basically equivalent to your proposed solution (the only difference being that in your version you also consider something like $-[v_0,v_1,v_2]$ to be a "simplex", rather than just being the formal negative of a simplex).

Comment: The following 1995 paper gives useful comparisons and history on oriented and ordered singular homology. http://tac.mta.ca/tac/volumes/1995/n1/1-01abs.html

Comment: This is not right. $[v_0, v_1, v_2]$ and $[v_2, v_0, v_1]$ are the same oriented simplex as usually defined and  $\{v_0, v_1, v_2\}$ and $\{v_2, v_0, v_1\}$ are the same simplex in $K$. They're not different in any context.

Answer (score 1):

My answer is based on what you commented of doing homology.

Let $K$ be a simplicial complex, $\sigma$ a $n-$simplex, with vertices $v_0, ..., v_n$. Let $\pi$ be a permutation of $\{1, ... , n\}$. We say that the orderings $(v_0, ..., v_n)$ and $(v_{\pi(0)}, ..., v_{\pi(n)})$ are *equivalent* if $\pi$ is an even permutation.

So, we define an **oriented simplex** $[v_0, ..., v_n]$ to be the class of the ordering $(v_0, ..., v_n)$.

Then one constructs $C_n(K)$ to be the group of functions from the set of *oriented* $n-$simplices of $K$ to $\mathbb{Z} $  such that $c(\sigma)=-c(\sigma')$ for $\sigma, \sigma'$ *different* orientations of the same simplex and $c(\sigma)\neq 0$ only for finite simplices $\sigma$. This is equivalent to say, $C_n(K)$ to be the free abelian group generated by oriented $n-$simplices of $K.$

The vertices are labelled so $d_i$ removing $v_i$ means exactly that (not removing the vertex in the $i-$th place).

I write $\partial_n:C_n(K)\rightarrow C_{n-1}(K)$, for an ordering $(v_0, ..., v_n)$ of $\sigma$,  $$\partial_n(v_0, ..., v_n)=\sum_{i=1}^{n} (-1)^n[v_0, ...., \hat{v_i}, ..., v_n],$$ where the "hat" means remove that vertex, that is what you wanted to call $d_i$.